# how programmatically capture streaming video url?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

I have been searching how programmatically capture streaming video url, like it does the Video Download Helper addon of Firefox, but i don't found any helpful info. This can be done with javascript ? Accessing the DOM ? or getting it somehow from some connection ?

Comment: Not by now, a way to figure it out would be inspecting the source code of Video Download Helper to see how it makes it. If you find something, please share it here